# JQuery IF input value matches specific word in any letter casing

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a few forms where people add data into a mysql database using JQuery validation and thought of an interesting question.  I was wondering how you would reject a specific word if written in lower or uppercase or any combination of the 2.  For example if I wanted to show an error if anyone entered the word "wordnumber1", "WordNumber1", "WoRdNuMbEr1", "WORDnumber1", etc, etc.  Here's an example format of the type of code I'm using:

```
if (word == "wordnumber1")
{
  $('.wordStatus').html("Invalid Word").removeClass("success").addClass("error");
  wordok = false;
}
```

I tried using indexOf() but that shows an error if you type in any character that matches

Thank you

Comment: Instead of displaying an error, can you not convert it to the case format you need?

Comment: Compare the entries by `.toLowerCase()`ing each. like `word.toLowerCase() === 'wordnumber1'`

Comment: Hmm, intersting - How could I convert it to lower case in the JQuery script?

Comment: You don't need jquery to do that. Check my answer, the only difference is that I'm using toUpperCase()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the inserted value uppercase and compare to the restricted word in uppercase

```
if (word.toUpperCase() == 'WORDNUMBER1'){
     //YOUR CODE HERE
}
```

If you want to check for various words you can have something like

```
words = ['WORDNUMBER1','WORDNUMBER2','WORDNUMBER3']

if ($.inArray(word.toUpperCase(),words) != -1) {
     //YOUR CODE HERE
}
```

Comment: haha i was just about to provide the .toLowerCase() function.

Comment: Thank you - Both toUpperCase & toLowerCase work brilliantly - Thanks again